# Python Socket (How to seperate FileName From File contents)

Tags: python, sockets

I have written two client and server python scripts were server is listening for client to send files following is my server code for listening files. The problems with the code i cannot separate filename from the file data. Following output is received *data.txtMyName*

```
def sendFileName(self):
        self.clientsocket.send("name:" + self.filename)
        print 'filename', self.filename

    def sendFile(self):

        f=open(self.filename,"rb")
        data= f.read(1024)
        while (data):
          if(self.clientsocket.send(data)):
           print "sending data"
           data = f.read(1024)
           #readByte = open(self.filename, "rb")
           #data = readByte.read()
           #readByte.close()
           #self.gateway.send(data)
        self.clientsocket.close()
        f.close


     def receiveFile(self,sock):
             data = sock.recv(1024)
             print 'filename', data.strip()
             f = open(data.strip(), "wb")
             data = sock.recv(1024)
             while (data):
               f.write(data)
               data=sock.recv(1024)
             f.close()
             self.server_socket.close()
```

Comment: You'll need to include the code for sending files also.

Comment: @aya i have included the code

Comment: how about you separate the filename somehow from the rest of the file? A null byte would probably do the trick...

Comment: just wondering `print 'filename ', data.strip()` with a blank ` ` ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your own simple protocol on top of TCP/IP to get it work. The simplest I would imagine is to add one special character (for example 0x00) between filename and file content. Receiving site could detect this char and split filename and file content.

More complicated protocol could also send file size so the receiving site could detect when transmission is finally over and if all bytes were send.
It will also be good to send acknowledge message to sender that receiver got whole file.

There is lot of transfer file protocols (TFTP, FTP) and they exist for a reason, because pure TCP/IP without any protocol on top is useless.